# Laravel get data from controller and send to view ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to get data from controller and send it in ajax. 
The script is in app.blade.php.

Controller

```
public function show()
{
    $number=Order::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();

    return $number;

}
```

Route

```
Route::get('product_number', 'OrderController@show')->name('product_number');
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "product_number",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

In console it shows me the html view.

Comment: There is no alert in your js. Do you mean console.log is not displaying anything or?

Comment: I edited it. It shows me the HTML view

Comment: @alphal, can you show the content of console here?

Comment: @alphal means there is a error

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma What should I do ?

Comment: @alphal try my solution

Answer (score 0):

try this so you can get the error

```php
public function show()
{
    try {
        $number=Order::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); die;
    }
    return $number;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{url('product_number')}}",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });

});
```